# Создание процедуры, проверяющую нагрузку тренеров в спортивном клубе

Tags: sql, oracle, процедуры

Необходимо создать процедуру, проверяющую нагрузку тренеров. Если тренер ведет больше 3-х групп в день (количество одинаковых lesson_coach_id за один день > 3), или время его занятий с одной группой совпадает со временем занятий в другой (lesson_star_date и lesson_end_date для одного тренера в один день пересекаются)
группе, или перерыв между двумя занятиями меньше 15 минут или больше 3-х часов (тут разница межу lesson_end_date и lesson start_date, как я понимаю), то 
такие сведения выдаются на экран. Если таких ситуаций нет, процедура выдает "Без
нарушений".

Понимаю, что задание непростое, чтобы его просто так сделать, прошу дать хотя бы наброски.

Имеется таблица:

Занятия

```
CREATE TABLE lesson
( lesson_id number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_section_id number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_coach_id number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_room number(5) NOT NULL,
  lesson_start_date date NOT NULL,
  lesson_end_date date NOT NULL,
  lesson_cost number(5),
  FOREIGN KEY (lesson_section_id) REFERENCES sections(section_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (lesson_coach_id) REFERENCES coachs(coach_id),
  CONSTRAINT lesson_pk PRIMARY KEY (lesson_id)
);
```

Comment: Привидите исходные данные, ожидаемый результат, и попытку решения.

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете за вас вашу работу/задание сделать целиком?

Comment: @0xdb да тут даже попыток решения не надо, видно что человек хочет свалить свою работу на других ...

Comment: @Kromster Это пусть автор думает, я сегодня уже два раза думал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание не сложное. Требуется почитать о выборке данных из таблиц с помощью `select from`. Порисовать временную шкалу.

1. Для выполнения первого задания потребуются работа с групповой функцией `COUNT` (выражение `GROUP BY`).
2. Очень похожий запрос был в реализации триггера предыдущего вопроса.
3. Объединяем нужные записи друг с другом, вычитаем.
4. Самое непростое. Я решал бы через `EXISTS` `NOT EXISTS`. Если не получилось бы, то смотрел в сторону аналитических функций.